# Parse.com: Fetch Array Column (Relation) Using Query

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfquery

I have a `PFQueryTableViewController` subclass which makes a query to a Parse.com table for data with a column named `messages`, which is of array type.

The query returns the data, except with messages being an empty array (although there is data in the table AND in the `messages` field).

Below is the query which I create for the Parse data:

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
    [query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [query includeKey:@"messages"];
    return query;
}
```

Weird part, once I update the Parse object and save it, reloading the table data fetches the array column's data.

Any idea why it returns an empty array with the initial query?

**EDIT:**

NSLog() output of the query result (from `- (void)objectsDidLoad:` ):

```
objects: (
    "<Conversation: 0x7f8590c6b0b0, objectId: 5rO7Y2R5hs, localId: (null)> {\n    ACL = \"<PFACL: 0x7f8590e61ec0>\";\n    messages =     (\n    );\n    user = \"<PFUser: 0x7f8590d9d260, objectId: M88Oz4annq>\";\n}"
)
```

Creating the relationship upon button click:

```
Message *newMessage = [[Message alloc] init];
//... set message properties
[newMessage saveInBackground];

if (!self.parseObject.objectId) {
    self.parseObject = [[MyParseObject alloc] init];
    [self.parseObject setUser:[User currentUser]];
}

[[self.parseObject messages] addObject:newMessage];
[self.parseObject saveInBackground];
```

The parseObject class above is what I'm querying.

Comment: It would help if you posted more code. What code creates the relation? What code saves it? And how is `queryForTable` being called, so we can be sure the save has finished?

Comment: @piojo, see update. Also, `queryForTable` is called automatically by the controller.

Comment: Is your query function being called immediately after the save function? If so, the data is probably just not saved yet. Or it's partially saved, with the user object being saved but not `newMessage`. But there are other things that I can think of that could go wrong, but I just don't know enough about what's happening. Also, if we get into tricky stuff about which objects need to be created in which order (and when an object needs to be saved before it can be used), that's shaky ground for me.

Comment: The `newMessage` object gets saved. The `parseObject` object gets saved with the `newMessage` object's pointer. Just the query does not return it with the rest of the data.

Comment: If this is a true ParseRelation object, the parse docs say its needs a separate query, and can't be included. Use an array list for that. But if we put that aside, you haven't answered my question--is your query function being called immediately after the save function? Because I know the object gets saved, I'm just not sure it gets saved soon enough.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I can pull to refresh later, after saving the object. Still same result.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. But is it a ParseRelation or an array? If it's a Relation, what makes you think it should work? The docs have no examples of `includeKey` being used for a Relation. (Read them more carefully.)

Comment: It's a column of type array. I've followed the example in the docs under the Relations section (sub-section on using arrays for relations).

Comment: Okay, I admit I'm now way over my head with this (language issues), but when you call this:

    `[[self.parseObject messages] addObject:newMessage];`

Is that correct? Because when I look at the docs, I don't see that API for `addObject`. I only see a version that takes an additional `forKey` argument. There is another `addObject` function, but it's not part of the Arrays API.

(I'm having a hard time going between object-oriented Objective-C and imperative Objective-C that's in the docs.)

Comment: I'm sorry for not stating this before, the `parseObject` is an object of a subclass of `PFObject` where messages is an array, hence the `addObject`. However, I've also tried the `forKey` approach.

Comment: Sorry I haven't been any help. I need to go now. Good luck, and I wish you debugging log statements that cut like lasers.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are saving your message is very time prone. As you aren't waiting for 'newMessage' to be saved yet. So it's ID value may be null.

Make sure the newMessage object is saved first, by placing the next code inside a completion block.

```
Message *newMessage = [[Message alloc] init];
[newMessage saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if(succeeded){
        if (!self.parseObject.objectId) {
            self.parseObject = [[MyParseObject alloc] init];
            [self.parseObject setUser:[User currentUser]];
        }

        [[self.parseObject messages] addObject:newMessage];
        [self.parseObject saveInBackground];
    }
}];
```

Without seeing the definitions of your Message and MyParseObject classes, I can't be much more helpful however.